# Truck moving uphill, object suspended from ceiling, determine acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration

> A truck is moving with constant acceleration $a$ up a hill that makes and angle $\phi$ with the horizontal. An object of mass $m$ is suspended from the ceiling of the truck by a light cord. If the pendulum makes a constant angle $\theta$ with the perpendituclar to the ceiling, what is $a$?

By vector addition, the tension in the rope becomes

$$mg+ma$$

Right? It will make the angle $\theta$ with the perpendicular of the ceiling. The triangle consisting of these vectors will have one side, $m$ times $a$, with angle ($\theta-\phi$) on the opposite side. Therefore I tried using the law of cosines, but it did not work out. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the tension on the rope will make angle $\theta$ with the perpendicular to the ceiling as mentioned in the problem statement, not with the ceiling itself.

The truck is moving uphill with acceleration *a*, therefore the mass hanging from the rope will experience an acceleration *-a* (to the opposite downhill direction). The three forces, 1. force from acceleration *-a* (in downhill direction), 2. force from gravitational acceleration *g* and 3. tensile force on the rope, are in equilibrium here and we can use [law of sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines). We just need to consider the two sides involving *-a* and *g* here and ignore the third side involving the tension on the rope. The angles between the forces can be derived using some simple geometry and then using the law of sines is a simple task. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics stackexchange. it's common practice on this forum to *not* answer homework questions explicitly but rather just give out some hints, just so you know.